# How can I log into an existing wordpress site locally on mac

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming, admin, local, bitnami

I already have a live existing wordpress site. I am trying to install wordpress locally for mac. I want to make edits of my site, but don't want my live site to look under construction. I have tried Bitnami and Local, but only see the option to create a new site and dont see a login to existing option. I appreciate any help, thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bitnami Engineer here,

You can also use the [All in One WP Migration Plugin](https://wordpress.org/plugins/all-in-one-wp-migration/) to migrate the data of your live site to the development one (this one can be the one we offer in our site: https://bitnami.com/stack/wordpress/installer). Once you test your changes, you can apply them in the live site.

You can find more information about it in our documentation

https://docs.bitnami.com/installer/how-to/migrate-wordpress/

Answer (score 0):

So you want to use your live database and do the changes in your local WP installation. It's much simple if you download your live database and import on localhost and do the changes.

Anyway if you want connect to live database follow this steps

Open *wp-config.php* Change the following values

**Database Name** Database Name used by live WP

**Database Username** Username used to access live Database

**Database Password** Password used by Username to access live Database

**Database Host** Live MySQL Hostname don't mention localhost or 127.0.0.1.

You can get this information from your hosting provider

Also you need enable Remote MySQL.